# Contact form is not responsive to the rest of the page

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure out how to make the contact form on my website responsive so it can be properly adjusted when checking the page on phone.

Here is the website:

https://ddahkickz.com/pages/contact-us
Password: ddah

I have little knowledge regarding this and need assistance if possible. Below you can check the code of the Shopify page. Thank you in advance for the assistance on the matter.

````
  {{ form.errors | default_errors }}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>contact form</title>
</head>

<body>

<center>

<link href="contact-form.css" rel="stylesheet">

<center><h1 style="font-size:2vw">CONTACT US</h1></center>

<div class="fcf-body">

    <div id="fcf-form">
        
        <div class="fcf-form-group">
            <label for="First Name" class="fcf-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="fcf-input-group">
                <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" class="fcf-form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fcf-form-group">
            <label for="Last Name" class="fcf-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="fcf-input-group">
                <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" class="fcf-form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fcf-form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="fcf-label">Your email address</label>
            <div class="fcf-input-group">
                <input type="email" id="Email" name="contact[email]" class="fcf-form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fcf-form-group">
            <label for="Message" class="fcf-label">Your message</label>
            <div class="fcf-input-group">
                <textarea id="Message" name="contact[body]" class="fcf-form-control" rows="6" maxlength="3000" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fcf-form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="fcf-button" class="fcf-btn fcf-btn-primary fcf-btn-lg fcf-btn-block">Send Message</button>
        </div>

    </form>
    </center>
    </div>

  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>

</div>

</body>
</html>

<style>

#fcf-form {
    display:block;
}

.fcf-body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    max-width: 35%;
}

.fcf-form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.fcf-input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.fcf-form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.fcf-form-control:focus {
    border: 1px solid #313131;
}

select.fcf-form-control[size], select.fcf-form-control[multiple] {
    height: auto;
}

textarea.fcf-form-control {
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: auto;
}

label.fcf-label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.fcf-credit {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #545b62;
}

.fcf-credit a {
    color: #545b62;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.fcf-credit a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.fcf-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .fcf-btn {
        transition: none;
    }
}

.fcf-btn:hover {
    color: #212529;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fcf-btn:focus, .fcf-btn.focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.fcf-btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
}

.fcf-btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
}

.fcf-btn-primary:focus, .fcf-btn-primary.focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fcf-btn-lg, .fcf-btn-group-lg>.fcf-btn {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.fcf-btn-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.fcf-btn-block+.fcf-btn-block {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

input[type="submit"].fcf-btn-block, input[type="reset"].fcf-btn-block, input[type="button"].fcf-btn-block {
    width: 100%;
}
  
</style>

{% endform %} ```
````

Comment: What you posted here is not the same as on your site. Please post [mcve] of what you actually have. Also you have an external stylesheet and an inline stylesheet

Comment: Are you referring to contact-form.css ? When I remove this line of code actually nothing happens. There is no contact-form.css in my Shopify directory. I will understand you if I am pain in the as* and do not want to assist me. I just don't understand everything

Comment: try using a `media query` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries. You can specify the width of the viewport at which the CSS properties should change. So for mobile you could do: `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {.fcf-form { max-width: //width you want the form to be; } }`

Comment: @Sarah - You should make that an answer

Comment: As mentioned by @Sarah, you need to use media queries.  At present, your form is set to **max-width:35%**.  Or set something like **width:35%** and **min-width:400px**

Answer (score 1):

Depending what width the form should be in mobile view, the [`media query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) is how you can make your application responsive. Here is an example of writing a media query for a small viewport. You can adjust the widths to how you want the form styled.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fcf-form { 
    max-width: //width you want the form to be; 
  } 
}
```